# jQuery get specific option tag text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

Suppose I have a drop-down list like:

```
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>Option A</option>
    <option value='2'>Option B</option>
    <option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

Given the value `'2'` (i.e., using a specific value, *not necessarily the selected one*), what selector can I use to get "Option B"?

I tried `$("#list[value='2']").text();`, but it is not working.

Comment: For this period of time, use: `$("#list option").filter(function () { return $(this).html() == "stuff"; }).val();`

Answer (score 1147, accepted):

It's looking for an element with id `list` which has a property `value` equal to `2`.
What you want is the `option` child of the `list`:

```
$("#list option[value='2']").text()
```

Comment: Thank you for this nickf.  Here is this answer expanded if you want to get the value dynamically: var selectValue = document.getElementById('list').value;  var selectOption = $("#list option[value=" + selectValue + "]").text();  ///good example nickf.

Comment: @Kevin, in that case, you might want to use the answer below this one. `$('#list option:selected').text()`

Comment: @nickf , and more simpler, `$('#list').val()`

Comment: @Derek ,val() will not give the text of the option, it will give its value, which in some cases (many I dare say) is not the same.

Comment: you should always use ``.trim()`` after ``.text()`` since some browser may add sometimes some spaces before and after the text that are invisible to the user but may lead to getting wrong values
``$("#list option[value='2']").text().trim()``

Answer (score 1274):

If you'd like to get the option with a value of 2, use

```
$("#list option[value='2']").text();
```

---

If you'd like to get whichever option is currently selected, use

```
$("#list option:selected").text();
```

Comment: To get the value instead of the text, you will need to write:-  


$("select#list").val();   


I know that this is not the actual answer of the question asked, but still thought of mentioning this point for newbies coming through Google.

Comment: I use $("#list option:selected").text() and $("#list option:selected").attr('value')

Comment: For getting the selected text (even though the question didn't ask for that specifically), this method is superior due to not having to know what the selected value is.

Answer (score 135):

This worked perfectly for me, I was looking for a way to send two different values with options generated by MySQL, and the following is generic and dynamic:

#### `$(this).find("option:selected").text();`

As mentioned in one of the comments. With this I was able to create a dynamic function that works with all my selection boxes that I want to get both values, the option value and the text.

Few days ago I noticed that when updating the jQuery from 1.6 to 1.9 of the site I used this code, this stop working... probably was a conflict with another piece of code... anyway, the solution was to remove option from the find() call:

```
$(this).find(":selected").text();
```

That was my solution... use it only if you have any problem after updating your jQuery.

Comment: supposedly this is the more efficient way to do it according to WebStorm 8.

Comment: While this answer is insightful and helped me with a problem I was having, to nitpick, it does not properly answer the question: _Please note that this is not asking how to get the selected text value, but just any one of them, whether selected or not, depending on the value attribute._

Comment: It's true @StubbornShowaGuy that it is not specified by value. The solution is assuming someone is looking for the label if the value is sent. But there's no reason for that if you can send both values at the same time... example var me = $(this).find(':selected'); var val = me.val(); var txt = me.text().trim(); ... In that case there's no need to make a second request.

Answer (score 108):

Based on the original HTML posted by Paolo I came up with the following.

```
$("#list").change(function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text()+' clicked!');
});
```

It has been tested to work on Internet Explorer and Firefox.

Comment: An alternative to this is: $("option:selected", this).text()

Comment: This is a better answer because it accounts for complex scenarios not just static html and simple javascript events.

Answer (score 37):

```
$("#list option:selected").each(function() {
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

for multiple selected value in the `#list` element.

Answer (score 37):

1. If there is only one select tag in on the page then you can specify select inside of id 'list'

   ```
   jQuery("select option[value=2]").text();
   ```
2. To get selected text

   ```
   jQuery("select option:selected").text();
   ```

Answer (score 24):

Try the following:

```
$("#list option[value=2]").text();
```

The reason why your original snippet wasn't working is because your `OPTION` tags are children to your `SELECT` tag, which has the `id` `list`.

Answer (score 19):

This is an old Question which has not been updated in some time the correct way to do this now would be to use

```
$("#action").on('change',function() {
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").text()+' clicked!');
});
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: This is definitely not correct **Please note that this is not asking how to get the selected text value**

Answer (score 17):

I wanted to get the selected label. This worked for me in jQuery 1.5.1.

```
$("#list :selected").text();
```

Answer (score 17):

```
$(this).children(":selected").text()
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this does not work when you have `optgroup` tag as a child of your `select` and the selected option is in this `optgroup`. use `$("#list option:selected").text();` which works even in this case

Answer (score 14):

You can get selected option text by using function `.text();`

you can call the function like this :

```
jQuery("select option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$("#list [value='2']").text();
```

leave a space after the id selector.

Answer (score 9):

While "looping" through dynamically created select elements with a .each(function()...): `$("option:selected").text();` and `$(this + " option:selected").text()` did not return the selected option text - instead it was null.

But Peter Mortensen's solution worked:

```
$(this).find("option:selected").text();
```

I do not know why the usual way does not succeed in a `.each()` (probably my own mistake), but thank you, Peter. I know that wasn't the original question, but am mentioning it "for newbies coming through Google."

I would have started with `$('#list option:selected").each()` except I needed to grab stuff from the select element as well.

Answer (score 9):

Use:

```
function selected_state(){
    jQuery("#list option").each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == "2"){
            jQuery(this).attr("selected","selected");
            return false;
        }else
           jQuery(this).removeAttr("selected","selected"); // For toggle effect
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    selected_state();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for getting val by internal field name instead of ID and came from google to this post which help but did not find the solution I need, but I got the solution and here it is:

So this might help somebody looking for selected value with field internal name instead of using long id for SharePoint lists:

```
var e = $('select[title="IntenalFieldName"] option:selected').text();
```

Comment: Solid solution.  Sorry it's in such a secret place down here.  You might want to find a more prominent place to provide this solution.  Maybe you could ask and answer a question of your own?

Answer (score 5):

A tip: you can use below code if your value is dynamic:

```
$("#list option[value='"+aDynamicValue+"']").text();
```

Or (better style)

```
$("#list option").filter(function() {
     return this.value === aDynamicValue;
}).text();
```

As mentioned in [jQuery get specific option tag text and placing dynamic variable to the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135825/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text-and-placing-dynamic-variable-to-the-value/12135848)

Answer (score 4):

I needed this answer as I was dealing with a dynamically cast object, and the other methods here did not seem to work:

```
element.options[element.selectedIndex].text
```

This of course uses the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) object instead of parsing its HTML with nodeValue, childNodes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution, you can also use a [context part of jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) to find `<option>` element(s) with `value="2"` inside the dropdown list:

```
$("option[value='2']", "#list").text();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a dynamic version for select multiple that would display what is selected to the right (wish I'd read on and seen `$(this).find`... earlier):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("select[showChoices]").each(function(){
            $(this).after("<span id='spn"+$(this).attr('id')+"' style='border:1px solid black;width:100px;float:left;white-space:nowrap;'>&nbsp;</span>");
            doShowSelected($(this).attr('id'));//shows initial selections
        }).change(function(){
            doShowSelected($(this).attr('id'));//as user makes new selections
        });
    });
    function doShowSelected(inId){
        var aryVals=$("#"+inId).val();
        var selText="";
        for(var i=0; i<aryVals.length; i++){
            var o="#"+inId+" option[value='"+aryVals[i]+"']";
            selText+=$(o).text()+"<br>";
        }
        $("#spn"+inId).html(selText);
    }
</script>
<select style="float:left;" multiple="true" id="mySelect" name="mySelect" showChoices="true">
    <option selected="selected" value=1>opt 1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value=2>opt 2</option>
    <option value=3>opt 3</option>
    <option value=4>opt 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get one of following ways

```
$("#list").find('option').filter('[value=2]').text()

$("#list").find('option[value=2]').text()

$("#list").children('option[value=2]').text()

$("#list option[value='2']").text()
```

```js
$(function(){    
    
    console.log($("#list").find('option').filter('[value=2]').text());
    console.log($("#list").find('option[value=2]').text());
    console.log($("#list").children('option[value=2]').text());
    console.log($("#list option[value='2']").text());
    
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>Option A</option>
    <option value='2'>Option B</option>
    <option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#list option[value='2']").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[...list.options].find(o=> o.value=='2').text
```

```js
let text = [...list.options].find(o=> o.value=='2').text;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<select id='list'>
    <option value='1'>Option A</option>
    <option value='2'>Option B</option>
    <option value='3'>Option C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use
$("#list option[value='2']").text();
for text of the option with value equal to 2
and you can use
$("#list option:selected").text();
for text of the selected option