# Using jquery, how do I remove an item from dropdown based ONLY on its text?

Tags: jquery-ui, drop-down-menu

When someCondition is true, I'm trying to remove a dropdown option that has "someText" as its Text.  I do not know its value.  It seems like this should work, but it does not.  When debugging, I see that someID is undefined.  Does anyone know if I've made some small syntax error?

```
function toggleSomeOption() {
    if (someCondition() == "Foo") {
        var someID = $("#myDropDown option[text='someText']").attr('value');
        $("#myDropDown option[value='someID']").remove();
    }
}
```

I've styled my code after [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241727/how-do-i-select-an-item-by-its-text-value-in-a-dropdown-using-jquery/241751#241751), but it won't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#myDropDown option").filter(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.text() == "SomeText";
}).remove();
```