# How to change selected text of DropDownList using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist having **id="ddlTitle"**.

It contains three values as mentioned below
**Mr.

Mrs.

Miss**

Current selected item is Mr.
I want to change the selected text to some other text of dropdownlist when page refresh.

I am using  **$('#' + ddlTitle + ' :selected').text(Title)**; where Title can be **Mr.** or **Mrs.** or **Miss**

There is one problem that if I use the above code, I am able to change the selected text but whatever was the selected text before, didn't appear in 
dropdownlist.

Example :
If current selected text is Mr. then after using this code **$('#' + ddlTitle + ' :selected').text('Miss');** Current selected text will become **Miss**
but values in dropdownlist becomes as below:

**Miss

Mrs.

Miss**

Where as previous values were

**Mr.

Mrs.

Miss**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have answer in this thread:

[How do I select an item by its text value in a dropdown using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241727/how-do-i-select-an-item-by-its-text-value-in-a-dropdown-using-jquery)

you can use this code for example:

```
$("#ddlTitle option").each(function() {
  this.selected = $(this).text() == Title;
});
```