# jQuery getting text value for a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this:

```
<select name="select_list_name" id="list_id">
    <option value="">Select Option</option>
    <option value="value1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="value2">Option 2</option>
    ...
    ...
</select>
```

I am trying to get the text value of the currently selected option in a select list. I looked at this thread: [jQuery get specific option tag text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text)
and tried this:

```
$("#list_id option:selected").text()
```

But this only gets me the first options text (`"Select Option"`) regardless of which option has been selected.

I tried another way:

```
$("[name=select_list_name] option:selected").text()
```

That gets me the first option's text concatenated with the selected options's text (`"Select OptionOption 2"` if I select Option 2).

Any idea on why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`$('#list_id :selected').text();` should give you the selected option's text.

Something else in your code must be wrong -- this piece of code **[really works](http://jsbin.com/exuhu3/2)**

Comment: I have tried that and it behaves the same way as the first option I tried.

Comment: I am doing something like this:
`var selectedText = $("#list_id option:selected").text();`
This is within another function. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: No, it should not; on jsbin I pasted your code in an anonymous function. Please paste your whole function or script...

Comment: I think there maybe an issue with another 'onChange' function being specified in the select list which is a plain javascript. I am trying to modify someone else's code. Just doing `document.form.select_list_name.options[selectedIndex].text` seems to work.

Comment: I found the issue. Was using the wrong id. There were two forms on the page with the same input names.

Comment: IMO my answer should be the correct one as I asked do you have more than one id called "list_id"

Comment: i had the same problem and found that i needed a space after the id selector. error : $('#list_id:selected').text();  corrected : $('#list_id :selected').text();

Answer (score 2):

This WORKS, 100%, do you have more than one id with 'list_id'?

```
$('#list_id :selected').text();
```