# get current text <select>

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
                 <select runat="server" id="sctFieldMain">
                 <option></option>
                   </select>
```

Script

```
   $(xml).find("FieldMain").each(function()
 { 
    var value=$(this).find('Title').text()
     $('#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %>').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",value).
      text(value)); 
  });

 alert($("#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %> option:selected").text());
```

this retrun <%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %>

or

```
alert($("#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %> option:selected").val());
```

this retrun undefined

or

```
alert($("#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %> option:selected").html());
```

return null

i like get Cureent Text. that selected

Comment: you don't need the semi colon at the end of you val() or text() BTW

Comment: have you tried just: $('#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %>').val();

Comment: Possible silly question, but any chance your js is in an external `.js` file and not on the page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
alert($("#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %> option:selected").html());
```

EDITED

Also your question duplicates [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643227/jquery-get-selected-text-from-dropdownlist).

Comment: @4111: You must do a simple check first to make sure there is at least one option on the list. Then it cannot return null.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the semi colon after the html() function and val does not return the html which is what your looking for.

```
alert($("#<%=sctFieldMain.ClientID %> option:selected").html());
```

However if you had the following and wanted the value "Example" then you should use val()

```
<option value="example">some test</option>
```

Comment: qestion =$("select#sctQuestion option:selected").html(); 
                        alert(qestion);            return null

Comment: Why are you referencing: select#sctQuestion ?