# Get Text Select That Runat="Server"

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, jquery-selectors, selection

```
   <select   id="Select1">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
  </select>

alert($("#Select1").val());
```

this code Is Correct And Return Current Value.

BUT

```
   <select runat="server"   id="Select1">
         <option></option>
  </select>

function parseXmlQuestion(xml)
{

   $(xml).find("Question").each(function()
  { 
     var value=$(this).find('Text').text()
     $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",value).
      text(value)); 
   });
```

}

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').val());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

or

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').text());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

or

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').html());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

return null or undefined .

Comment: Is it actually appending the `option` elements?  When you inspect it on the client-side (with something like FireBug) what actually happens?  The second example adds more variables than just the `runat="server"`.

Comment: what does the `<%=Select1.ClientID %>` suppose to return ?

Comment: Why have you re-posted this question?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297778/get-current-text-select

Comment: first of all, you need to put ';' at the end of var value=$(this).find('Text').text()

Comment: Put an alert within you each() call and make sure it is hitting that

Comment: @nEEbz actually its not really required, its good practice but not that will fix his problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you are a bit weird and you are helping us less each time you answer...

Here is what you should do.

1. test that this returns the correct id. `<%=Select1.ClientID %>` which should be `Select1`
2. check your xml, that is, correct, (use json preferably it's far easier) including the caps of your xml tags. so do either `console.log(value)` or `alert(value)` if you haven't evolved yet :)
3. `parseXmlQuestion()` should be called somewhere on the page otherwise you just having a sitting duck not being shot or not telling it to run in other words

Answer (score 0):

u need to remove  `<option></option>` from

```
   <select runat="server"   id="Select1">
         <option></option> <-- your values get added after this so probably the null is coming from here
  </select>
```

it should be like

```
   <select runat="server"   id="Select1"></select>
```

Comment: from where you are removing the `option`?

Comment: in html code that remoove in script error say append do not defined

Comment: dont know what you meant to say but only remove it from the `html` ...don't remove it from script... do not remove `select` just remove the `option` element

Comment: `<%=Select1.ClientID %>` is probably empty or `NULL` so `$('#').append(...)` would result in error