# Get current text <select runat="server">

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get Text Select That Runat=“Server”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298203/get-text-select-that-runat-server)

1:

HTML

```
  <div id="dialog">
       <select   id="Select1">
         <option>1</option>
         <option>2</option>
         <option>3</option>
       </select>
 </div>
```

Script

```
    $("#dialog").dialog({ "ok": function () {    alert($("#Select1").val()); });
```

this code Is Correct And Return Current Value.

BUT BUT BUT BUT

2:

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">
      <select runat="server"   id="Select1">
         <option></option>
     </select>
  </div >
```

Script

```
function parseXmlQuestion(xml)
{

   $(xml).find("Question").each(function()
  { 
     var value=$(this).find('Text').text();
     $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').
      append($("<option></option>").
      attr("value",value).
      text(value)); 
   });
   alert($('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').val());
 }//Fill `Select1` 
//add correct information to `Select1`


 $("#dialog").dialog({ "ok": function () {    `ALERT()` });
```

Fire 'Ok' Function:

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').val());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

or

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').text());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

or

```
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %>').html());
alert( $('#<%=Select1.ClientID %> option:selected').val());
```

return null or undefined .

I like Get Current Text selected.

I think Problem in  `runat="server"` in `<select>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Text Select That Runat="Server"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298203/get-text-select-that-runat-server) and [get current text `<select>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297778/get-current-text-select) | reposting your question does not give you better answers. Edit your question instead, provide more useful information, comment on answers and reply to comments.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that items are kept in viewstate by ASP. Anything you add or remove without involving ASP is essentially going to get ignored. There are most likely ways around this, but if you're looking to dynamically populate a control with a collection of items (such as a DropDownList) you're probably going to have to use more than jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to avoid having ASP.NET changing your control's ID, by setting the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to Static.

Comment: Why not?  HtmlSelect inherits from System.Web.UI.Control, which has a property called ClientIDMode.