# How to get the text of an option by passing value of option with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get select option text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text)

I have a drop downlist as like:

```
<select id="systemMessageList" name="systemMessageList">
    <option value="-1">--- Choose One ---</option>  
    <option value="120">niempo</option>  
    <option value="119">quartero</option>  
    <option value="118">mileno</option>  
</select>
```

I want that: I will pass the value for example `119` and it will return the text `quartero` in JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$('option[value="'+$('#systemMessageList').val()+'"]').text();
```

so if `119` is selected it will return: `quartero`

or you can create some sort of function that gets the text for any option value:

```
function getOptionText(option){
    return $('option[value="'+option+'"]').text();
}

getOptionText(119); // yields quartero
```

Comment: or change `$('#systemMessageList').val()` to whatever value you want to get the text for

Comment: that too @codethis, ill add that to the answer

Answer (score 5):

For the text of the selected option, you need:

```
$('#systemMessageList option:selected').text();
```

For the value you can just use

```
$('#systemMessageList').val();
```

**Edit:** the other answers are probably what you want. I'm just showing you how to get the text and value of whichever option is selected.

Comment: I agree with you but from a performance point $('#systemMessageList').find(':selected').text(); would be better

Answer (score 3):

```
var text = $('#systemMessageList option[value="119"]').text();
```

Comment: just missing a single quote here! Perfect answer though!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getOptionText(value){
    return $('#systemMessageList option[value="' + value + '"]').text(); 
}

alert(getOptionText(119));
```