# finding option text based on value of select control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select control that looks like this:

```
<select name="MyName" id="MyID">
  <option value ="1">1 day</option>
  <option value ="2">2 days</option>
  <option value ="3">3 days</option>
  <option value ="4">4 days</option>
<select>
```

I'm looking to get the text of the option based on the value. For instance, if I input 2, it should return "2 days".

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get select option text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text) | There are already  lot of similar questions. Just search for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 alert($('option[value=2]', $('#MyID')).html());
```

Comment: ok, this works. Made a small tweak:  alert($('option[value= ' + MyVal + ']', $('#MyID')).html()); so that I can put MyVal as a paramater. Thanks

Comment: This is a very strange way. Much easier: `alert($('#MyID option[value=2]').text())` as already shown in the question I linked to. Why serialize the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

try this out:

```
$('#MyID').change(function(){

   alert($("option[value="+this.value+"]", this).text()); 
     //added so it only finds options in this select element  

})
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bzscs/

Comment: He said the *text*, not the value. *Edit*: Ah, you've edited. Good deal.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder i fixed my answer ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to arrange if so that MyID is part of the selector, something like $(#MyID option...); I feel like I'm close but I'm not there yet.

Comment: you can also add MyID in your selector like 
$('#MyID option[value="' + YourValue + '"]').html();

Answer (score 0):

Another could be:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    alert($('option[value = "' + $(this).val + '"]', this).text());
});
```

If you have more than one select.