# get the text of the option from the value of the combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery get select option text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text)

let's say that i have the value of the combo but `without make a selection`, now i want to know how can i make a selector that brings me the text of that value

the html

```
<select class=".ddlOperators" >
      <option value="1">Value 1</option>
      <option value="2">Value 2</option>
      <option value="3">Value 3</option>
      <option value="4">Value 4</option>
 </select>
```

I tried like this

```
$(".ddlOperators option").find('1')
```

notes that 1 was the value of the option of the combo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".ddlOperators option[value='1']").text();
```

Also, your class for the `select` element should not be preceded by a dot, it should be:

```
<select class="ddlOperators">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/L5xsu/)