# jquery selection if option.value equal something, mark a selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some question about jquery selection. In my case, how to match if the `option.value` equal something, mark a `selected` for it. [Online code here](http://jsfiddle.net/WnEfJ/)

repeat code again. It caused `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLOptionElement> has no method 'val'`, how to work as my hope? Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 3;
    $("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
        if((this).val()==num){
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");    
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div id="selection">
    <label>Label1:</label>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="1">V1</option>
        <option value="2">V2</option>
        <option value="3">V3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Label2:</label>
    <select class="select">
        <option value="4">U1</option>
        <option value="5">U2</option>
        <option value="6">U3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe this post can help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/196684/508702

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You made a typo

Instead of `(this).val()` you should use `$(this).val()` in your if statement. `this` refers to a HTMLObject, `$(this)` would refer to a jQuery object. Because the `.val()` method is part of the jQuery framework, you can't use it on HTMLObjects. But I'm sure you knew that because it looks very much like a small typo.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 3;
    $("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==num){ // EDITED THIS LINE
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");    
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit**

You could optimize your loop by adding a `return false;` (`break;` for vanilla loops) when you have found your element so it doesn't keep looping elements while we're already "done".

However, you should look at **Nicola Peluchetti's** answer for a more efficient and cleaner code.

Answer (score 21):

You have a typo and to set the option as selected you should use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and not attr(). in any case you could do

```
var num = 3;
$("div#selection select.select option[value="+num+"]").prop("selected", true);
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/YRBrp/

EDIT - the typo of course is what Tim S. pointed out, you should use `$(this).val()` and not `(this).val()`

Comment: Also, I've edited my post and referred to this answer because it's so sexy

Comment: This works in the case of OP because the value is numeric. If like me you need this to work with string values, change to `$("div#selection select.select option[value='"+num+"']").prop("selected", true);` by adding in the single quotes around the `"+num+"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem starts here

$("div#selection select.select ***option***").each(function(){
        if(***(this).val()***==num){

change it to

```
$("div#selection select.select").each(function(){
if($(this).val()==num){
```

and all your problem solved. You might want to change the .each to .change if you are thinking of having the script triggered everytime the selection is changed.

Answer (score 0):

The first time where you refer to `this` it is not a jQuery object it is a DOM object and a DOM object doesn't have the `val()` method. You should either use `this.value` och `$(this).val()` try this:

```
$("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==num){
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");    
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works well. Just update 'this' with $(this). If there are no any other select dropdowns you can omit 'div#selection select.' like below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var num = 3;
    $("select option").each(function(){     
        if($(this).val()==num){
            $(this).attr("selected","selected");    
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

```
    $("div#selection select.select").val(num);
```

if your select box is multiple select, you can try

```
    $("div#selection select.select option").each(function(){
      if($(this).val()==num){ 
        $(this).attr("selected", true);    
      }
   });
```