# Why is this javascript not working - select box if

Tags: javascript, select

I have this code on my site. The idea is to hide a specific class when a specific select box value is selected.

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var txt = 'Marketing';
$("div.ginput_container select#input_3_1 option").each(function(){
    if($(this).val()==txt){
        $('.mar').hide();    
    }

   });
});
```

The result I'm getting is .mar class being hidden as soon as the page is loaded. I can't see the error, I have also tryied with

> var num = 1

but I have the same issue.

Comment: Why are you using such a complicated selector? Just use `$("#input_3_1 option")`. Also, why are you using `.each` on a single element?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572545/jquery-selection-if-option-value-equal-something-mark-a-selected 
I was using this thread as guide. I will try with your suggestion.

Comment: Is the `$(this).val()` exactly the same? As far as case? If it's `marketing` instead of `Marketing` it will not work.

Comment: Yes, they're exactly the same Dylan.

Comment: You're hiding `.mar` if _any_ of the options has the value `Marketing`, you're not just checking the selected option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var txt = 'Marketing';
    $("#input_3_1").change(function () {
        if ( this.value == txt ) $('.mar').hide();
    });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cyxh/

---

If you want to show `$('.mar')` when a different option is selected, use `toggle` instead:

```
$('.mar').toggle( this.value != txt );
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cyxh/1/

---

If you want this to also run on page load (before an option is manually selected), trigger the change event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var txt = 'Marketing';
    $("#input_3_1").change(function () {
        $('.mar').toggle( this.value != txt );
    }).change();
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Cyxh/2/

Comment: Thank you Joseph!! I added else ($('.mar')).show(); if different is selected, is that good or I should use your .toggle() ?

Comment: @Jaypee - It's all the same. `toggle` is just a convenience method, to make your code more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the loop in the first place

Attach your select to the change() event handler and that should be it..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("select#input_3_1").on('change', function() {
         var txt = 'Marketing';
         if(this.value === txt){
             $('.mar').hide();    
        };

     }).change()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide ".mar" class when the value is changed and it equals "Marketing" try

```
$("#input_3_1").change( function() {
    if( $(this).val().toUpperCase() === "MARKETING" ) {
        $(".mar").hide();
    }
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/okimow/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#input_3_1").change(function(){
  if ($("#input_3_1").val()=='Marketing'){
    $(".mar").hide();
  }
});
```