# How to select then post multiple forms and pass to php?

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have a page that has multiple forms on it. I have checkboxes in front of each form. When  a selection box with the id of action is selected it submits each of the forms associated with the checkboxes. I just can't seem to get this to work though.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#action").change(function(){
        var selectVal = $('#action :selected').val();
        if(selectVal === "list-all"){
           $("form").each(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        var checkValue = $(".prelistCheckbox:checked").val();
        if(form.attr('id')==checkValue){
        $.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize(), function(data){
                // `form` is still the particular form submitted,
        // and `r` will be the results of posting that form.
        document.write(form.serialize()+form.attr('id'));                   
        });
        }
    });
          }
     });
});
```

I borrowed this code from one of the many answers to this question but it posts all of the forms and not just the ones that have been selected. I have tried changing it from just selecting form elements to attempting to select the id of a form that is equal to the value of the checkbox that is checked. But I don't understand how to return a value so all I've managed to make a boolean that return true for the forms I've selected.

Comment: `$('form')` gives you all the forms in the document, you have to come up with some criteria to filter out the forms you don't want.

Comment: I know but I can't decide how to limit it. I wanted to just bring back results that had an id that was equal to the value of the checkbox. But it would only run the first result then stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just serialize everything and allow the PHP to determine which checkboxes preceding which forms are checked.   I understand your intention, but it's not worth the trouble.

Comment: So leave the code alone and create a php function to determine what information was checked?

Comment: Yes.  The amount of data sent just in a few forms is tiny.

Comment: It would be between about 10 and 100 forms, it pulls information from a database and puts some of the information in the forms. So how many forms come in would dictate how many would be submitted. At least until I figure out paging.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came across how to place a variable inside my selector
    $('form[id=' + $("checkbox:checked").val() + ']')
I'm still working with my code to make it work as it should but at least now I'm targeting what I wanted in the first place. 
here is the link that helped me: [jquery selection if option.value equal something, mark a selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572545/jquery-selection-if-option-value-equal-something-mark-a-selected)

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a simple case of simply using an:

```
   if(isset($_POST['CHECKBOXNAME'])){
     //run code for this form
   }
   if(isset($_POST['SECONDCHECKBOXNAME'])){
     //run code for this other form
   }
```

All inside the:

```
   if(isset($_POST['SUBMITBUTTONNAME'])){

   }
```

? Sincere apologies if I've miss understood your question.

Comment: I am using a for loop to pull rows from a database and create forms for them. The form id are created from an id variable that corresponds to the row in the database. What I wanted was a way to list only certain forms and update a database if a checkbox was checked. If you've ever seen manager pro in ebay where it lets you add notes to a bunch of fields, that's what I was going for. I eventually came up with something that works... Mostly. I still have to figure out how to get $.post data to return what I want. Right now it returns all the html on my page.