# How can I get html <option> tag's content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-select

I have a easy select tag:

```
<select>
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
</select>
```

Then I want use jQuery get the option's content:

```
var s=$('select option');
for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){
    console.log(s[i]);
}
```

it would only show `"<option>"`,without the content.

If I use `console.log(s[i].html());`, it would tell me it is wrong.

So how can I get the content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get select option text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text)

Comment: Can someone tell me why it is not working with the .html() method ? 
It seems to me that it should...

Comment: @Euloiix: Because inside the `for` loop are not jQuery objects, and therefore jQuery's `.html()` method is not available.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Very glad I asked, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need jQuery to get the text content.

An `HTMLOptionElement` has a `.text` property.

```
var s = $('select option');

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s[i].text);
}
```

---

Although if you want the `.outerHTML` of the element *(a little confused by your question)*, you could do this...

```
var s = $('select option');

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(s[i].outerHTML);
}
```

...though this only recently became available in Firefox, so you could create a method to patch it...

```
function outerHTML(el) {
    return el.outerHTML || document.createElement('div')
                                   .appendChild(el.cloneNode(true))
                                   .parentNode
                                   .innerHTML;
}
```

...and use it like this...

```
var s = $('select option');

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    console.log(outerHTML(s[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by 'content' you mean the text value of the option, try this:

```
$("select option").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to extract element's text node value