# JQuery retrieving text instead of value of select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the value from a select list but JQuery is returning the text within the options of the select.

I have the following simple code.

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option selected="selected">All</option>
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

I then use the following JQuery, which I thought would get me the value

```
var myOption = $('#myselect').val()
```

but when I look at `myOption` I get the text of 'One' or 'two'?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. You say you want to get `1` or `2` but your are getting `one` and `two` instead? If yes, I cannot reproduce your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/xmvFS/. Make sure your `option` elements actually have a `value` attribute or provide a demo. If it is vice versa and you want to get the text, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-select-option-text

Comment: Is that all your code? Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/38F6F/

Comment: is that answer work for you ???

Comment: i agree with Henry P, http://jsfiddle.net/QNRjg/ I think the problem is elsewhere. Are the values added in the HTML just the way you ve shown in your question? Or are they populated later through a ajax call maybe.

Comment: I cannot see why either I agree that this should work and I have been using the change function also, I did not include here to simplify

Comment: OP is calling `1` as the `value` and `One` as the `text` in `<option value="1">One</option>`

Comment: @Deviland as we cannot reproduce the problem from the example you have posted, you may have to post more code. e.g. are you using `myOption` anywhere else?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

update : add val().

```
console.log($('#myselect').val());

// all option's value
$('#myselect').find('option').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
    console.log($(this).val());
});

// change event
$('#myselect').change(function(){
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').text());
    console.log($(this).find(':selected').val());
});
```

​
demo : http://jsfiddle.net/yLj4k/3/

Comment: OP asked for how to get the value rather than the text

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem because the jQuery `Val()` function was in my head and I actually defined the options as `<option val='xx'>` instead of `<option value='xx'>`. That's what is causing the problem. See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xmvFS/23/).

```
<select id="myselect">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<select id="myselect2">
   <option val="1">One</option>
   <option val="2">Two</option>
</select>

<script>
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

The first `select` will alert "1" or "2" and the second `select` will alert "One" or "Two".

Comment: Thanks I was going crazy with this... then realized I typed "val" instead of "value" :)

Comment: I did id instead of value.  Same problem.

Comment: damn... I really did not know what's going on, and I knew .val() works as I use it all the time. I typed val="" as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

to get the text value easiest way is

For selected option Text :

```
$("#myselect option:selected").text();
```

For selected option value:

```
$("select#myselect").val();
```

Comment: @devnull69 - check the answer i wrote both how to get value and how to get text of selected option ...

Comment: the question seems to be "why is `val()` returning the text", I'm not sure how that is answered.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n6VzA/1/)

```
$("#myselect").change(function() {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**edit**

Hiya

working demo here: using text http://jsfiddle.net/QtjTq/3/ && using val here http://jsfiddle.net/QtjTq/4/

like this for accessing text() -  `var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').text()`
for accessing value -  `var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').val()`

to elaborate more:

**for value** if you want to access `value=` attribute use `.val()`;

**for text** if you want to get the text i.e.`one or two` then use selected options `... option:selected` with `.text()` api.

further if you want to read http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-using-val-vs-text

hope this helps :) cheers

```
var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').text() //**or whatever suit you** 
var myOption = $('#myselect option:selected').val()


<select id="myselect">
   <option value="1">One</option>
   <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```