# Jquery to get SelectedText from dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to get the selected Text from the dropdownlist using Jquery.

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownList("SelectedCountryId", Model.CountryList, "(Select one Country)")
</div>
```

Given below is the Jquery that I am using. But this is not working.
I tried

```
var selectedText1 = $("#SelectedCountryId").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
```

and is returning [object object]. But how to read the selected text?

Next I tried

```
var selectedText2 = $("#SelectedCountryId:selected").text();
```

Then it's returning empty.

I also tried

```
var selectedText2 = $("#SelectedCountryId option:selected").text();
```

This also returned empty.

I am able to return the selectedID using

```
var selectedID = $("#SelectedCountryId").val();
```

But why not the selected text?

Is there anything wrong with my Jquery here? Please help

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#SelectedCountryId").change(function () {

                var selectedText1 = $("#SelectedCountryId").val($(this).find(":selected").text());
                var selectedText2 = $("#SelectedCountryId:selected").text();
                alert("You selected :" + selectedText1 + selectedText2 );


            });
```

This is the HTML for my dropdown  below

```
<select id="SelectedCountryId" name="SelectedCountryId"><option value="">(Select one Country)</option>
<option value="19">USA</option>
<option value="10">Germany</option>
<option value="12">Australia</option> </select>
```

Comment: Possible Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684

Comment: `you selected :" + selectedText1 + selectedText2`? as far as I know you can select just one option with `select` tag!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I had the same problem yesterday :-)

```
$("#SelectedCountryId option:selected").text()
```

I also read that this is slow, if you want to use it often you should probably use something else.

I don't know why yours is not working, this one is for me, maybe someone else can help...

Comment: $("#SelectedCountryId option:selected").text()
is not working for me .its just returning empty

Comment: @Millar: are you sure you do not have a different problem. Can you please post your html output.

Comment: and you changed the value ;-)? have you tried to change it several times in a row. Can you try to add a value other than an empty string at the first option. It looks to me like you are always selecting the first one...

Comment: I am able to read selected value with   var selectedID = $("#SelectedCountryId").val();  and I can see diff values based on my selection .But I am not finding a way to get the selected text

Comment: I tried this code:

`<select id="SelectedCountryId" name="SelectedCountryId"><option value="">(Select one Country)</option>
<option value="19">USA</option>
<option value="10">Germany</option>
<option value="12">Australia</option> </select>

<script>
 $("#SelectedCountryId").change(function () {
    var selectedText2 = $("#SelectedCountryId option:selected").text();
    alert("You selected :" + selectedText2 );
});
</script>`

This is working great for me with jquery-1.7.1   -- sorry, linebreaks are removed :-(

Comment: @ Philipp Mehrwald Thank you  for helping  me .It started working after I deleted the  first statement 
  var selectedText1 = $("#SelectedCountryId").val($(this).find(":selected").text());

Answer (score 10):

Without dropdown ID:

```
$("#SelectedCountryId").change(function () {
    $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Today, with jQuery, I do this:

```
$("#foo").change(function(){    
    var foo = $("#foo option:selected").text();
});
```

`\#foo` is the drop-down box id.
Read [more](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/).

Comment: Should to keep this code inside $(document).ready(function () {});

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be on this line:

```
            var selectedText2 = $("#SelectedCountryId:selected").text();
```

It's looking for the item with id of `SelectedCountryId` that is selected, where you really want the option that's selected **under** `SelectedCountryId`, so try:

```
$('#SelectedCountryId option:selected').text()
```

Comment: I tried $('#SelectedCountryId option:Selected').text()
 but its returning empty

Comment: I think i accidentally capitalized the `selected`

Answer (score 1):

first Set id attribute of dropdownlist like i do here than use that id to get value in jquery or javascrip.

**dropdownlist:**

```
 @Html.DropDownList("CompanyId", ViewBag.CompanyList as SelectList, "Select Company", new { @id="ddlCompany" })
```

**jquery:**

```
var id = jQuery("#ddlCompany option:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//Code to Retrieve Text from the Dropdownlist 

$('#selectOptions').change(function()
{
     var selectOptions =$('#selectOptions option:selected');
     if(selectOptions.length >0)
     {
        var resultString = "";
        resultString = selectOptions.text();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `<select>`, `$(this).val()` inside the `change()` event returns the value of the current selected option. Using `text()` is redundant most of the time, since it's usually identical to the value, and in case is different, you'll probably end up using the value in the back-end and not the text. So you can just do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/DW5kF/

```
var selectedText2 = $(this).val();
```

**EDIT:** Note that in case your `value` attribute is empty, most browsers use the contents as value, so it'll work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Get text from a dropdown multiple

```
var texts = [];
$('#list :selected').each(function(){
    texts.push($(this).text());
});
```

texts now contains a list of selected text

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#SelectedCountryId_option_selected")[0].textContent
```

this worked for me, here instead of `[0]`, pass the selected index of your drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this

```
    var listbox = document.getElementById("yourdropdownid");
    var selIndex = listbox.selectedIndex;
    var selValue = listbox.options[selIndex].value;
    var selText = listbox.options[selIndex].text;
```

Then Please alert "selValue" and "selText". You get your selected dropdown value and text

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#selectnumber').change(function(){
                alert('.val() = ' + $('#selectnumber').val() + '  AND  html() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').html() + '  AND .text() = ' + $('#selectnumber option:selected').text());
            })
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <select id="selectnumber">
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
            <option value="3">three</option>
            <option value="4">four</option>
        </select>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Click to see Output Screen]

Thanks...:)