# Trying to understand $_POST and Database

Tags: php, database

Here's the html structure:

```
<select name="marke" class="marke">
<option value="1">Bosch</option></select>

<select name="modell" class="modell">
<option value="2">Nocria 14 LBC</option></select>
```

Here is my Php string (simplified)

```
$modellz = $_POST['marke']. ' ' .$_POST['modell'];
$insertQuery = "INSERT INTO producz (model)
VALUES
('" . $modellz . "')";
```

Im trying to get the name inside the `<option>` - tag to Post into the database.
But with this code I just get the values.
So when i run this i get `1 2` in the database.

But I want `Bosch Nocria 14 LBC`

OBS: I NEED THE VALUE attribute for my jquery selection script.

Please help!

Comment: What you have written makes no sense.

Comment: If you remove the `value` attribute from your html options, it'll post the text content of the selected option by default.

Comment: your HTML structure is invalid and the php isnt much clearer..

Comment: `<option value="Nocria 14 LBC">Nocria 14 LBC</option>`, and let me introduce you to a friend of mine called [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Do **not** build SQL [by mashing strings together](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You will need to get the text of the selected option.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text

Comment: And don't denormalise your database like that. Having `1` and `2` in the data is good. Store them as a pair of values that reference foreign keys in your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the HTML. The `value` for each `<option>` tag is what's sent in the POST request.

Change the HTML to:

```
<select name="marke" class="marke">
<option value="Bosch">Bosch</option></select>

<select name="modell" class="modell">
<option value="Nocria 14 LBC">Nocria 14 LBC</option></select>
```

and you will see the results you desire.

Also, please validate/sanitize your form-input before saving into the database. If you're using mysql functions, try `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

If jQuery needs access to the original ID for each option, I would suggest one of two methods. Either add a separate attribute to each option, such as rel: `<option value="Bosch" rel="1">Bosch</option>`, or keep your code as-is (`<option value="1">Bosch</option>`) and have PHP aware of the ID/value combinations.

The actual database-structure could, and possibly *should*,  modified to support the actual IDs instead of textual values.

Answer (score 4):

The `value` of the option is what gets passed to the server, if you want to receive the text within the option instead just remove the `value` attribute altogether:

```
<option>Nocria 14 LBC</option>
```

Will submit that actual string when its selected.

Other than that, please read up about SQL Injections because your current PHP code is vulnerable to attacks.

Comment: @oBo - That is a detail that you should have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

either make value='Bosch' or create an array in your php that converts '1' to the string you require.

This:

```
<select name="marke" class="marke">
<option value="Bosch">Bosch</option></select>

<select name="modell" class="modell">
<option value="Nocria 14 LBC">Nocria 14 LBC</option></select>
```

or

```
<?
Options = Array();
Options['1'] = "Bosch";
Options["2"] = "Nocria 14 LBC";
?>
```

and use Options[insert] to get the real value

Also remember to use mysql_real_escape_string or string->real_escape() for security

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to set the value of the option to Bosch and Nocria. POST stores what ever the option value to its corresponding `<select>` name.
Try this

```
<select name="marke" class="marke">
<option value="Bosch">Bosch</option></select>

<select name="modell" class="modell">
<option value="Nocria 14 LBC">Nocria 14 LBC</option></select>
```