# jQuery get specific option tag text and placing dynamic variable to the value

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$('#NameDropdown').change(function(){

                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "http://localhost:8081/crownregency/getInfoUser.php",
                    data: {id: $('#NameDropdown').val(), checker: 1}, // 1 is to get user info
                    success:function(data){

                    $temp = data['Type'];
                    $get = $("#UserTypeDropdown option[value = '$temp']").text();
                    $('#UserType').attr('value', $get);
                }               
            });
        });
```

I have a problem with regard to placing the returned variable from ajax to the value.
 $get = $("#UserTypeDropdown option[value = '$temp']").text(); how do i solve this? pls help.. this question is connected to: [jQuery get specific option tag text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
$get = $("#UserTypeDropdown option[value = '$temp']").text();
```

To:

```
$get = $("#UserTypeDropdown option[value='"+$temp+"']").text();
```

You could also use the `filter` method:

```
$("#UserTypeDropdown option").filter(function() {
     return this.value === $temp;
}).text();
```

Comment: @Vohuman thanks for solution,  Is it possible to change a selector or find another way to avoid concatenating strings to make the selector.

Comment: @Vohuman +1 and thanks. To me this code seems much better! But considering the performance do you think the first approach is faster than using filter ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi You are welcome! I prefer the `filter` method too. If performance is the key, jQuery should be avoided in the first place. You can select the `select`  element and filter the matching `option` using a simple `for` loop. The performance differences of those code snippets are negligible. If you want to test them: http://jsperf.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
$get = $("#UserTypeDropdown option[value = '" + $temp + "']").text();
```