# How to apply a function to two elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two elements `#DateTimeStart`, `#DateTimeEnd`, I would like apply my  `datetimepicker` to both.

With this code I cannot have the result.. any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // This does not work
    $('#DateTimeStart', '#DateTimeEnd').datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is like but with less code

```
// This code works
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#DateTimeStart').datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });  
    $('#DateTimeEnd').datetimepicker({
        addSliderAccess: true,
        sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just separate selector with comma:

```
$("#DateTimeStart, #DateTimeEnd").datetimepicker({
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
});
```

In jQuery documentation it is called as [**Multiple Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: May I ask you an explanation? In my code I have the elements separated by comma but it does not work. Your version works great. It is not good use ''?

Comment: Your example code has them separated by quotes. The correct code is a single string.

Comment: Ok you have reply to my comment with your edit. Many thanks I will accept your answer.

Comment: Wow 7 upvotes in a minute for a simple jQuery selector. Good job lol :)

Comment: @GibboK `$("#element1, #element2")` is not the same as `$("#element1", "#element2")`. The second is the same as `$("#element2").find("#element1")`.

Comment: @AlienWebguy Believe me, [some](http://stackoverflow.com/a/178450/1249581) can get [even](http://stackoverflow.com/a/306904/1249581) more [upvotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/196687/1249581) ;)

Comment: Haha yea 2008 questions are flooded with votes. +1 by the way ;)

Comment: @AlienWebguy Yeah, and *the very most* of popular questions already have answers. So to get really high graded answer nowadays is close to impossible. Hope this answer will also have +1000 some day in future :D

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class to both the elements say 'datepickerclass' and then use the below code
`$('.datepickerclass').datetimepicker({
    addSliderAccess: true,
    sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
});`
This way you can have any number of elements having datepicker attached