# How to navigate through relations in Grails with Javascript (or JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

Let's say we have a domain class `Country` with the next relationship:

```
Town town
```

And a domain class Town with:

```
Integer id
String town
```

The select works well fine with the following line of code (I'm using Grails Fields plugin):

```
<f:field bean="countryInstance" property="town" input-optionValue="town"/>
```

I want to get the optionValue, but the next code examples get the id:

```
var townName= document.getElementById("town").value;
var townName= document.getElementById("town").options[document.getElementById("town").selectedIndex].value;
```

The next code didn't work (this is the attempt to navigate through classes with Javascript):

```
var townName= document.getElementById("town").town.value;
```

How could I get the optionValue (or navigate through the relationship) to get `String town` instead `Integer id`?

Answer (score 2):

Using plain javascript, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vCkh8/), [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

```
var el = document.getElementById("town");
// value
el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
// text
el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
```

Or with jQuery, [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text):

```
$("#town option[value='2']").text()
$("#town option:selected").text()
```

Comment: It gets the value with `.text` (but NOT with `.value`). Thanks mate! :)