# Trying to get the HTML from option element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

I have a select field and I'm trying to get the HTML within the selected HTML. It keeps returning as undefined.

I've read answers saying to user the .val() function but the value and the HTML aren't the same so it won't work.

HTML:

```
<select id="my_SiteUsers" style="width:250px;" onchange="RefreshGroupLists()">
        <option value='default' disabled="disabled">Select a user</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var userText;
userText = $('#my_SiteUsers').html();

//check if default user selected  alert(user);
  if(user!="default"){
    var removeConfirm = confirm("You are about to delete "+userText+"from SharePoint. Are you sure?");
    if(removeConfirm){
      $.SPServices({
        operation:"RemoveUserFromSite",
        userLoginName: user,
        async:true
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you expect to get "Select a user" or "default" as a html.

Comment: Select a user is what I need but for whatever option is selected.

Comment: I really don't get it. You show only one element in your select. In the real case, do you have more elements, i.e. options representing every user?

Comment: Yes there are more options but they are populated dynamically based on the site the page is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what you need is actually [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
var userText = $("#my_SiteUsers option:selected").text();
```

`html()` will return undefined because there is actually no HTML inside the option element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use

```
$("#my_SiteUsers option:selected").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that rather then getting the actual html of the select box, you want to get the selected user, am I right? To do that, use

```
var userText = $("#my_SiteUsers option:selected").val();
```

Comment: Won't the val() function return the value and not the content? <option value='I don't want with'>I want this</option>

Comment: According to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text you can use .text() rather then .val() to get this