# Getting dropdownlist text from jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am very new with jQuery what I want to ask is getting dropdown list text from jQuery.
My dropdownlist is like that:

```
<select name="Branch[currency_id]" id="Branch_currency_id">
<option value="">Select Currency</option>
<option value="cu-001">Singapore Dollar</option>
<option value="cu-002">US Dollar</option>
</select>
```

with jQuery I can get dropdownlist value like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#Branch_currency_id').val();
}
```

It can only get the value of dropdownlist like cu-001, cu-002 but I don't wanna get like that what I want to get is Singapore Dollar, US Dollar by using jQuery. Can I get like that if so how can I get? Anyone please help me! Thanks! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get specific option tag text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simple approach](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/)

```
$('#Branch_currency_id option:selected').text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log($('#Branch_currency_id option:selected').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sel_txt = $('#Branch_currency_id option:selected').text();
    alert(sel_txt);
});
```

See the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pGESS/)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
alert($("#Branch_currency_id option:selected").text());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#Branch_currency_id option:selected").html();
```

OR

```
$("#Branch_currency_id option:selected").text();
```

Comment: space between option and id is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
alert($('#Branch_currency_id').find('option:selected').text());
```

or

```
alert($('#Branch_currency_id option:selected').text());
```