# How do I select displayed value as opposed to VALUE options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have the following SELECT combobox that is populated dynamically with ajax and httphandler web service (.ashx).

When SELECT combobox is dynamically populated, it looks like this:

```
<select name="selectid" id="selectid">
<option value="">-Select an option-</option>
<option value="1">Test1</option>
<option value="2">Test2</option>
<option value="3">Test3</o4tion>
<option value="4">Test5</option>
<option value="5">Test6</option>
<option value="6">Test7</option>
  </select>
```

Below is the js:

```
function getText() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'rulings.ashx',
        dataType: 'json'
    })
    .done(function(textInfo) {
        $(textInfo).each(function(i, texts) {
            $('<option>').val(texts.dbtextID).text(texts.textToBeDisplayed).appendTo( $('#selectid') );


        })
    });
}
```

When we display the values from the dropdown, it displays the VALUE options instead of the displayed text.

Example from the combobox above, it displays 1 instead of Test1.

How do I modify the script to show displayed text instead of VALUE options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Fetch the text instead of the value onChange ?

Comment: @harsha,

yes, exactly. 

We do have a summary page to display user's selections.

On that summary page, if user selects VALUE option 1, we would like to display Text1 instead of value option of 1.

Hope this clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code , just put it inside

```
$(document).ready(function(event){
    $("#selectid").on('change',function() {
        //alert($("#selectid option:selected").text());
        $('#summTextvalue').html($("#selectid option:selected").text());
    });
})
```

The [**ON**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in jQuery can bind events to dynamically created elements.

or you can also do something like

```
function _bindEvent()
{
    $("#selectid").on('change',function() {
        alert($("#selectid option:selected").text());
    });
}
```

and call `_bindEvent()` from your AJAX done method

Comment: I think that for your solution to work, it needs to be integrated with the script I posted and that's where I am having problem.

Comment: The first solution seems to be getting the displayed text on the alert. This is great but I would rather have it display in the summary section.

So, instead this:

`<p>Name: <span id="summTextvalue"></span></p>`, I like the value from your solution. Any ideas?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh : Look at the modified answer

Comment: BINGO!

Thanks so very much for your kindness and assistance.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh : Glad to be of assistance

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get text, instead of value.

```
$('#selectid').change(function(){

   var selectedVal=$(this).val();
   alert($(this).children("option[value='"+selectedVal+"']").text());

});
```

Comment: Isn't this a round about way of doing things ;-)