# Get value of selected option from drop down using jquery.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have a problem when I get the values ​​of Selected options.

Let me explain I have a list of options :

```
<select>
   <option value='1'>Option1</option>
   <option value='2'>Option2</option>
   <option value='3'>Option3</option>
   <option value='4'>Option4</option>
   <option value='5'>Option5</option>
</select>
```

I get the values ​and I inserts them into a variable for each Selected option and I put them in an array like this :

```
$("select option:selected").each(function()
{
      var listValO = new Array();
      var idOption = $("select option:selected").val();
  listValO.push(idOption);
 });
```

If I choose only one selected option, it works but when I select several options at the same time, the each () function inserts in the array the same value for the number of selected options.

when I click on the submit button, the array contains listValO several times the same value.

```
<select>
   <option selected value='1'>Option1</option>
   <option selected value='2'>Option2</option>
   <option selected value='3'>Option3</option>
   <option>Option4</option>
   <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

listValO returns just 3 times [1,1,1]. In fact, it seleted the first which I clicked or I want in my array [1,2,3].

Sorry for English mistakes if any. I hope you understand my problem and thank you for your future response.

Comment: Use `$("select").val();`

Comment: You have to set attribute `multiple` for SELECT element in order to be able to select multiple options at once, then use @Satpal's suggestion which will return an array

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get specific option tag text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SXr8t/2/ | http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SXr8t/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as the other answers (using multiple attribute, and using $(this)), you are re-declaring the array for each occurrence of a selected option. Try declaring it outside:

```
var listValO = new Array();

$("select option:selected").each(function()
{
      var idOption = $(this).val();
      listValO.push(idOption);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to add the `multiple` attribute to the select so you can select multiple options. Second, you're redeclaring a new array inside the each callback, so at the end you'll only ever have one option.

You should use `.val()` instead:

**Markup:**

```
<select multiple>
   <option selected value='1'>Option1</option>
   <option selected value='2'>Option2</option>
   <option selected value='3'>Option3</option>
   <option>Option4</option>
   <option>Option5</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var optionsArray = $("select").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute multiple in select to select multiple value:

```
 <select multiple="multiple">
   <option selected value='1'>Option1</option>
   <option selected value='2'>Option2</option>
   <option selected value='3'>Option3</option>
   <option>Option4</option>
   <option>Option5</option>
 </select>
```

Js code: You are iterating over the selected options, you should rather iterate over to select itself to ensure that selected options are added to array once only.

```
var listValO = new Array();
$("select").each(function()
{
listValO.push($(this).val());
});
//console.log(listValO) for test purpose
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2tG36/2/)**