# Retrieve text inside option tag with jquery

Tags: jquery

i would like to ask you help.

If i have an  tag with a specific (value="yyy") and some text, how can i retrieve this text or check if it is equal to a specific string if the option is selected, through jQuery?

```
<option name="xxx" value ="yyy">text</option>
```

I know that the .val() function retrieves the *value="yyy"* and not the *text*. I need to get (and check) the *text* string.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get specific option tag text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Comment: Why are you giving the `option` a `name` tag? That's normally in the `select`.

Answer (score 1):

please see fiddle

http://fiddle.jshell.net/RrD74/

html:

```
   <select id="mySelect">
        <option name="xxx" value="1">text opt 1</option>
        <option name="xxx" value="2">text opt 2</option>
        <option name="xxx" value="3">text opt 3</option>
    </select>
```

js:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#mySelect").change(function () {
            alert($("#mySelect option:selected").text());
        });


    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but if I have more then one option?
Your example retrives all text inside the options tag...
I want to get the text inside only the specific chosen one

Answer (score 1):

The code I believe you are looking for is:

```
var my_val = "yyy";
var txt = $('option[value='+my_val+']').text();
if(txt == "text"){
  // do stuff here
}
```