# Selecting JSON return value by option TEXT

Tags: jquery, json

I have some jQuery with JSON - there is one line that selects the proper state in a SELECT element - here is the line:

```
if (data.state) $('#state').val(data.state);
```

If works fine for the options like this:

```
<option value='NJ'>NJ</option>
<option value='PA'>PA</option>
```

`data.state` always will equal the text, like "PA" or "NJ" - but I've needed to change my options to this:

```
<option value='17'>NJ</option>
<option value='27'>PA</option>
```

So `(data.state) $('#state').val(data.state);` no longer works...

I'm wondering if I can change this line to somehow select the option by the TEXT, not the value...

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance
PS - I did try to figure this out reading other similar requests on StackOverflow - but I'm just lost at this point....jQuery is kind of new to me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery get specific option tag text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Comment: Does not the `.val()` method select the value when called on a select form field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#state option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == data.state) {
       $('#state').val($(this).val());
       return;
    }
});
```

It loops each option until it finds matching text then sets the value.

**untested