# How to access properties of html elements?

Tags: jquery

I select all html elements with a special class using jquery:

```
myElements = $('.myElement');
```

And i iterate over the elements using the each function:

```
myElements.each(function () {

});
```

How can i now access properties or functions from the html element like the `text()` function for example.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation for `.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/)? Does it answer your question?

Comment: `.text` is not a property of HTML elements; did you mean `.textContent`?

Comment: There's no `text` property. Please search for specific properties/questions.

Comment: `myElements.each(function() { console.log($(this).text()); }`

Comment: [Highly related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196684/jquery-get-specific-option-tag-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "special id" is called a class. . (dot) is for class and # is for id.

Example: If you have a lot of span-tags with text, you can run through all of them using `.each()` and then grab the text using `.text()`

```
<span class="myElements">Test 1</span>
<span class="myElements">Test 2</span>
<div class="myElements">Test 3</span>

$(".myElements").each(function () {
    console.log( $(this).text() );
});

//Console output
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
```

This will log every `.myElements` (all the elements with class = myElements) to the console.

As you're inside a function(), you can use `$(this)` to target each element as you iterate through them.