# Remove select option with specific value

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

How can I remove `<option value="0">Value 0</option>` from the `<select>` menu based on the value `0`?

```html
<select id="someid">
  <option value="0">Value 0</option>
  <option value="1">Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need Prototype JS to do this.

**Removing an option by index:**

```js
var select = document.getElementById('someid')
select.removeChild(select.options[0])
```

```html
<select id='someid'>
    <option value='0'>Value 0</option>
    <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
</select>
```

**Removing an option with a specific `value`:**

```js
var select = document.getElementById('someid')
select.removeChild(getOptionByValue(select, '0'))

function getOptionByValue (select, value) {
    var options = select.options;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (options[i].value === value) {
            return options[i]  
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

```html
<select id='someid'>
    <option value='0'>Value 0</option>
    <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
</select>
```

**Or, inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196687/7256039):**

*(**Edit:** [RobG submitted this technique before me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41113516/7256039); all credit hereafter to him. I saw his comment critiquing my answer and began editing my post accordingly, but didn't scroll down far enough to see his answer as well, which had addressed that issue already.)*

```js
var select = document.getElementById('someid')
select.removeChild(select.querySelector('option[value="0"]'))
```

```html
<select id='someid'>
    <option value='0'>Value 0</option>
    <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: While this is correct, it doesn't answer the question of removing an option with a specific value. :-/

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to include an alternative option for that more general use case.

Comment: @gyre @RobG - Great technique if I can get it to work.  In RobG's `inspired` solution, how do I supply a variable value in place of `0` ?    Say my ID value is `var tValue = 1108 ;` - how can I inject that intothe `querySelector()` ?  I have tried several methods and none of them are working.  Keep getting `The node to be removed is not a child of this node` error using `siteIDs.removeChild(siteIDs.querySelector( 'option[value="' +tValue+ '"]')) ;` - but the node def exists.

Comment: `select.querySelector("option[value='0']").remove();`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a selector to get an option with a specific value, then remove it. The following uses *querySelector*, but you could also loop over all the options and find the one(s) with the required value and remove them the same way.

```js
function removeOption() {
  var optValue = document.getElementById('i0').value;
  var errorEl = document.getElementById('errorMessage');
  var optElement = document.querySelector('option[value="' + optValue + '"]');
  if (optElement) {
    errorEl.textContent = '';
    optElement.parentNode.removeChild(optElement);
  } else {
    errorEl.textContent = 'There is no option with value "' + optValue + '"';
  }
}
```

```css
#errorMessage {
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select id='someid'>
    <option value='0'>Value 0</option>
    <option value='1'>Value 1</option>
</select>
<br>
Remove option with value: 
  <input id="i0">
  <button onclick="removeOption()">Remove option</button>
  <br>
  <span id="errorMessage"></span>
```